# RESTApi - what should be the method when the actions is not sure

Tags: java, rest

I have 4 Apis that I expose, and I don't know what method should I use for them (POST/PUT/DELETE).

The DB object (let's call it User) contains

```
{"id", "foreignId1", "foreignId2"}
```

I have 4 methods -

```
assignForegin1
unassignForegin1
assignForegin2
unassignForegin2
```

In each one, I'm getting only 2 parameters - 1 id and 1 foreignId (after that I'm creating a User with the relevant fields out of it).
Assign - if there is no id, I'm creating a new one with this foreignId, and if it exists, I override/assigning the new foreginId.
Unassign - I'm removing the foreginId from this id, and if the id contains no foreginIds, I delete it.

So, assign is half PUT and half POST, and the unassign is half PUT and half DELETE.

What will be the best practice in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: if you don't know what it should do, you should first figure out what it should do. as long as you're not clear on that, don't code it

Comment: maybe redesign api and use something like standard CRUD (create-update-delete-listValues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API should follow [single responsibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954230/rest-api-should-single-api-have-multiple-responsibilities), it should only assign the foreign fields and should not create/delete if not present.

In your way, the end-user of the API doesn't know that you will delete the object if the object with `id` doesn't have that `foreignId`, he will also not know that a new object will be created if an object with an `id` doesn't exist. As a best practice, the client of your API shouldn't know about your implementation.

I would suggest you divide the APIs into multiple CRUD APIs. Lets call your object as foreign

```
createForeign
  type: POST
  input: foreignId1, foreignId2
  output: Foreign

assignForeignId1:
  type: PUT
  input: id, foreignId1
  output: Foreign

assignForeignId2:
  type: PUT
  input: id, foreignId2
  output: Foreign
```

In case the id doesn't exist in case of `assignForeignId1`, the API should throw an error and the client should call `createForeign` API if he wants to create one.

Comment: you raised some very good points...and what about the deletion in case the object doesn't contain any foreign key after unassigning? and should I add an unassign method as well?

Comment: Thanks, @DviN, That's a tricky question, the solution for this mostly depends on your use case. If you delete the object after unassigning, won't you want to assign any new foreign field in future to that object?

Comment: I will, but I'll create a new one on demand...and I only delete in case there are no foreignId left.. so should the unassign method be PUT or DELETE...? ‍♂️

Comment: Then you should have it as PUT as you are modifying the object.